# Why do we use a try block to throw exceptions. can't we simply throw and catch them without a try block. What is its importance?

Tags: php

I am trying to figure out the need of try block in exception handling.

I am learning custom error handling in php and the code is as follows:

```
class customException extends Exception{
      public function errorMessage(){
        return "Error at line ".$this->getLine()." in ".$this->getFile()."<br>".$this->getMessage()." is not a valid email address";
      }
    }
    $email="someone@example.com";
    try{
      if(!filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        throw new customException($email);
      }
    }
    catch(customException $e){
      echo $e->errorMessage();
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733462/php-custom-exception-handling Please check this you will get idea.

Answer (score 3):

The code being executed in the `try` block may throw different types of exceptions

```
try {
    thingThatMightBreak();
}
catch (CustomException $e) {
    echo "Caught CustomException ('{$e->getMessage()}')\n{$e}\n";
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Caught Exception ('{$e->getMessage()}')\n{$e}\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you throw an exception without a try/catch block, a fatal error occurs. An error message appears citing the reason for this avoidable circumstance: "Fatal error: Uncaught Exception", and your program terminates without  executing the remaining code; see [here](https://3v4l.org/dlhUn).  The [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) mentions that this is the usual outcome:

> unless a handler has been defined with set_exception_handler()

Setting the exception handler avoids seeing the "Fatal error" message and allows the exception to be handled as you wish, but after the handler stops executing the program ends too; see [here](https://3v4l.org/tZ3Fa).

The try/catch block provides the code an with an opportunity to attempt execution.  If an exception should arise, it can be safely handled by catching it which prevents the program from suddenly stopping, as follows:

```
<?php

try {
  $myvar = null;
  if (!isset($myvar)) {
     throw new Exception("unset variable");
  }
} catch (Exception $e) {

   echo $e->getMessage();
}

echo "\nStill carrying on and on ...\n";
```

See [demo](https://3v4l.org/Z0lWn)

Answer (score 2):

Uncaught exceptions will terminate the execution of the program.

By the way, it's also possible to throw exceptions and handle them out of a try/catch block.
Here is the documentation page of php funtion [set_exception_handler()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php)

Answer (score 1):

try/catch is for handling exceptions and recovering from them. If you throw without a catch, your program will stop executing. If an exception occurs and you catch it, you can do things with it such as echoing it like you are currently doing.